# How do I get the content of pop-up window that suddenly appears in WebView?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-webview

I always find answers here stackoverflow but this one I haven't found yet. My problem is how to get the content of a pop-up window that suddenly appears when loading a page.

My idea is to load the url in the WebView and get the content of the pop-up window that appears. However, I can't find anything related to it.

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: What is the kind of popup? Is it native like confirmation, alert?

Answer (score 0):

You can set WebChromeClient with overriden onJsAlert method for your WebView

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html

Comment: As I've understood it, onJSAlert is initiated by the webview or app. What I need is to get the content of a pop-up window that unexpectedly appeared and was initiated by the page I am trying to open.

For example, I opened www.ebay.com and suddenly a pop-up window containing promo ads appeared. How do I get the content of that pop-up window?

Comment: You said that it is an alert and alert is initiated by the page. You just hook alert opening event in your webview in which you are opening page. If you are talking about custom alerts (like divs over the page) then there is no common way to accomplish this.